# When can I Register a Domain Name that's expired?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, godaddy, domain-registrar

A domain name I've been eyeing, has not been renewed by it's registrant this year. The domain was with godaddy.com all these years.

According to godaddy's documentation:

> Day 43    We assign the domain name to the winner of the expired domain
>   name auction, backorder, or closeout. If there are no bidders, we
>   return the domain name to the registry.

That Day 43 ended on the 19 Nov, 2015, but I still cannot register the domain name, and it shows as `Not Available`

Whenever I check with whois.godaddy.com, I get the message:

> Registrar: GODADDY.COM, LLC 
>   Whois Server: whois.godaddy.com
>  
>   Creation Date: 05-OCT-2007
>  
>   Updated Date: 26-NOV-2015
>   Expiration Date: 05-OCT-2015
>
> Nameserver: No nameserver
>
> Registry Status: redemptionPeriod

What does this mean, and when can I register this domain?